# How to reason about Go channel blocking in Go Concurrency Patterns fan-in example?

Tags: go, concurrency, channel

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func boring(msg string) <-chan string { // Returns receive-only channel of strings.
    c := make(chan string)
    go func() { // We launch the goroutine from inside the function.
        for i := 0; ; i++ {
            c <- fmt.Sprintf("%s %d", msg, i)
            time.Sleep(time.Duration(rand.Intn(1e3)) * time.Millisecond)
        }
    }()
    return c // Return the channel to the caller.
}

func fanIn(input1, input2 <-chan string) <-chan string {
    c := make(chan string)
    go func() {
        for {
            c <- <-input1
        }
    }()
    go func() {
        for {
            c <- <-input2
        }
    }()
    return c
}

func main() {
    c := fanIn(boring("Joe"), boring("Ann"))
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println(<-c)
    }
    fmt.Println("You're both boring; I'm leaving.")
}
```

This is an example from Rob Pike's talk on [Go Concurrency Patterns](https://go.dev/talks/2012/concurrency.slide#33). I understand the idea behind the fan-in pattern and I understand that the order of messages printed in main is non-deterministic: we just print 10 messages that turn out to be ready.

What I do not completely understand, however, is the order of calls and what blocks what.

Only unbuffered channels are used so, as per the documentation, an unbuffered channel blocks the sender.

The `boring` function launches a goroutine that sends strings to the unbuffered channel `c`, which is returned. If I understand correctly, this inner goroutine is launched but doesn't block `boring`. It can immediately return the channel in `main` to the `fanIn` function. But `fanIn` does almost the same thing: it receives the values from the input channel and sends them to its own channel that is returned.

How does the blocking happen? What blocks what in this case? A schematic explanation would be perfect because, honestly, even though I have an intuitive understanding, I would like to understand the exact logic behind it.

My intuitive understanding is that each send inside `boring` blocks until the value is received in `fanIn`, but then the value is immediately sent to another channel so it gets blocked until the value is received in `main`. Roughly speaking, the three functions are tightly bound to each other due to the use of channels

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How does the blocking happen? What blocks what in this case?

Each send on an unbuffered channel blocks if there is no corresponding receive operation on the other side (or if the channel is `nil`, which becomes a case of having no receiver).

Consider that in `main` the calls to `boring` and `fanIn` happen sequentially. In particular this line:

```
c := fanIn(boring("Joe"), boring("Ann"))
```

has order of evaluation:

1. `boring("Joe")`
2. `boring("Ann")`
3. `fanIn`

The send operations in `boring("Joe")` and `boring("Ann")` have a corresponding receive operation in `fanIn`, so they would block until `fanIn` runs. Hence `boring` spawns its own goroutine to ensure it returns the channel before `fanIn` can start receiving on it.

The send operations in `fanIn` have then a corresponding receive operation in `main`, so they would block until `fmt.Println(<-c)` runs. Hence `fanIn` spawns its own goroutine(s) to ensure it returns the out channel before `main` can start receiving on it.

Finally `main`'s execution gets to `fmt.Println(<-c)` and sets everything in motion. Receiving on `c` unblocks `c <- <-input[1|2]`, and receiving on `<-input[1|2]` unblocks `c <- fmt.Sprintf("%s %d", msg, i)`.

If you remove the receive operation in `main`, `main` can still proceed execution and the program exits right away, so no deadlock occurs.

Comment: Thank you! The unintuitive part for me is why there is no deadlock if `main` doesn't receive anything and proceeds execution. When we create the `c` channel in `main`, I expect everything to be blocked until there is something to receive the values. Obviously, it works differently

Comment: Well, answering my own question, I think the reason is that `main` is not blocked and can proceed so there is no deadlock here. For some reason, I had thought that the channel inside `main` should block it too

Comment: @DonDraper there is no deadlock until you attempt a blocking operation (when no other goroutine can proceed). If in main you never receive on `c`, main can simply proceed to termination

Comment: Got it, thank you. I have accepted your answer :)